# How auto update pageload using Sqldependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, sqldependency

I am trying to create and run a sqldependency method from a web form class, where I have a "UpdateMethod", which I implemented using a window-form as reference.
However the web-form version of the method, does not update the page-load automatically on the client-side, when there is a change in the database, whereas window-form does.

Window form method version:

```
   delegate void GridDelegate(DataTable table);      
   private void UpdateGrid()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User]";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                dep = new SqlDependency(cmd); //Passing Command to SQL dependency 
                dep.OnChange += dep_OnChange;
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(rdr);
                }
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Invoke((GridDelegate)delegate(DataTable table)
        { dataGridView1.DataSource = table; }, dt);
    }
```

Web form version of the method:

```
      private void UpdateGrid()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User] order by uploadDate desc";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {

            try 
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDependency dep;
                    dep = new SqlDependency(cmd); //Passing Command to SQL dependency 
                    dep.OnChange += dep_OnChange;

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(rdr);
                        // GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I tried adding in a try..Catch statement in the web form version, but I am getting no errors from it.  Please advice, in how I can test this method further, in order to resolve this issue. Any hints/advice would be most appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: I think you need websocket for this kind of communication...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Is their example I can use which shows a websocket working with sqlDepepency.  I found some links which uses SignalR with websockets.  I would also like ask, how the window-form is able to create this logic without the websocket? Please advice, if possible.

Comment: Have a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Comment: @deostroll any real sample using SignalR, not chat sample ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mockup. I do not have a sql server to work with; hence I've done my example with timers (threading). I have used SignalR for the purpose. Make sure the browser is also a bit modern (IE10 +, Chrome, Mozilla, etc which supports websockets).

1. Create your hub class with a constructor

The constructor initializes and fires the timer thread. The thread executes code which instructs the hub to call a particular js method on the client(s) (i.e. all those browsers that are connected to the hub).

This particular js method will host the logic to refresh our gridview which is inside an updatepanel.

2. Write the necessary javascript to do the refresh (aspx)

The aspx page is a simple in design. It has an updatepanel inside which you have a gridview bound to a sqldatasource, and a linkbutton whose main responsibility is to refresh the grid data (server-side). The code for this is very simple, and will be shown below later. You can notice that for the refresh to work we are simulating a manual click on the LinkButton control (hosted inside udpatepanel).

3. write necessary logic to connect with the hub (aspx)

This is code which connects to the hub, and writes the js method which should be called when you receive the server message.

Also make sure you have the owin startup class files added to the project. Refer [SignalR tutorials](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) for more signalr stuff.

---

### DataHub.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApp.SignalR.GridUpdatePanel
{
    public class DataHub : Hub
    {

        public DataHub()
        {
            Debug.Print("Ctor executed...");
            Timer tmr = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.RefreshThread), null, 1000, 5000);
        }

        //Method which invokes the client js code...
        public void Refresh()
        {
            Clients.All.refreshData();            
        }

        public void RefreshThread(object obj)
        {
            Debug.Print("RefreshThread Called...");
            Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

### SignalRPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="SignalR Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SingalRPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.SignalR.GridUpdatePanel.SingalRPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPageHeadScripts" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPageBody" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PName" HeaderText="PName" SortExpression="PName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PAge" HeaderText="PAge" SortExpression="PAge" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PersonsDbConnectionString1 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Persons] WHERE [Id] = @Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Persons] ([Id], [PName], [PAge]) VALUES (@Id, @PName, @PAge)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PersonsDbConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [PName], [PAge] FROM [Persons]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Persons] SET [PName] = @PName, [PAge] = @PAge WHERE [Id] = @Id">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PAge" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PAge" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Refresh</asp:LinkButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPageBottomScripts" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script>
        function refreshGrid() {
            console.log('grid refresh');
            var lnk = document.getElementById('<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>');
            lnk.click();
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var chat = $.connection.dataHub;
            chat.client.refreshData = function () {
                refreshGrid();
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log('hub started...');
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Here I have used the following master page.

### Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApp.SignalR.GridUpdatePanel.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphPageHeadScripts" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphPageBody" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphPageBottomScripts" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally the code-behind of the main aspx page will look as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApp.SignalR.GridUpdatePanel
{
    public partial class SingalRPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
        }       

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("LinkButton1_Click");
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```